# Audio card shows up in lspci but not in aplay, 18.04

Tags: sound, alsa, 18.04

for some reasons I do not fully understand, my Terratec Aureon 5.1 PCI shows up in lspci | grep audio:

```
$ lspci |grep audio
05:00.0 Multimedia audio controller: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8738/CMI8768 PCI Audio (rev 10)
```

but not in aplay -l:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I installed pavucontrol and it doesn't show up in the config tab either.

It worked well on ubuntu 16.04 though.

Anyone would be able to help?

Thanks in advance.

Edits:

```
$ dmesg | grep snd
[    6.987976] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    6.987980] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    7.022637] snd_cmipci: `0x330' invalid for parameter `mpu_port'
[    7.022639] snd_cmipci: `0x388' invalid for parameter `fm_port'
[  214.411439] snd_cmipci: `0x330' invalid for parameter `mpu_port'
[  214.411442] snd_cmipci: `0x388' invalid for parameter `fm_port'

$  cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf 
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

Comment: I believe the correct driver for your device is `snd_cmipci`. Is it loaded? `lsmod | grep snd` If not, load it and see if there is any improvement: `sudo modprobe snd_cmipci` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It is not loaded indeed. So I tried to add it and I got this: 

$ sudo modprobe snd_cmipci

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'snd_cmipci': Operation not permitted

Comment: Please show us: `dmesg | grep snd`.

Comment: I've added to the main question what I get from dmesg and what's in alsa-base.conf. It's a fresh install from 10 minutes ago, I reinstalled just in case I messed up before trying to follow your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug referred to in the alsa-base.conf file is about 12 years old and, obviously, is now ineffective. Documentation on `snd_cmipci` is very hard to find and is also, typically, old.

As an experiment, I suggest that you remove the offending line:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Change this line:

```
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
```

To comment it out; that is, make it ineffective, like this:

```
#options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor. Reboot.

Any improvement?

Comment: That was it, it's now working perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour